# Sorting wordpress posts with ACF date & time picker

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF pro date & time picker to populate the field "fixture_date" for the custom post type "fixtures". Running a `new wp_Query` returns all of the posts but I cant sort them by the custom field's date & time.

The date & time picker is set to output as `j F Y - g:i a` from within ACF Pro.

My code so far:

```
<table id="fixturestable">
    <tbody>
        <?php $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'fixtures', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'meta_key' => 'fixture_date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_type' => 'DATETIME'
            );

            $fixturesloop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ($fixturesloop->have_posts() ):?>
            <?php while ( $fixturesloop->have_posts() ) : $fixturesloop->the_post();?>
                <tr>
                    <td class=""><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                    <td class=""><?php echo(get_field('fixture_date'));?></td>
                    <td class=""><?php echo(get_field('competition'));?></td>
                    <td class=""><?php echo(get_field('venue'));?></td>
                    <td class=""><?php echo(get_field('result'));?></td>
                    <td class=""><?php echo(get_field('score'));?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?> 
            <?php endif;?>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed nothing, simply re-uploaded the template files and it's started to sort correctly.